# What was New World Computing's "Hall of Heroes"?

Tags: anvil-of-dawn

After finishing [*Anvil of Dawn*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anvil_of_Dawn), a message appears that congratulates the player and shows the achieved game score.

They invite you to send your game score to this address:

> Hall of Heroes
>   New World Computing
>   PO Box 4302
>   Hollywood CA 90078

As there is no [New World Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_World_Computing) anymore (well, and as the game is 20 years old), I guess this won’t work anymore.

But does anyone know what would have happened back then? What was the point in sending your score to them? What was this *Hall of Heroes*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [*SynTax*](http://www.syntax2000.co.uk/issues/) issue 42 (from 1996) contains a [review of *Anvil of Dawn*](http://www.syntax2000.co.uk/issues/42/anvilofd.rev.txt), in which the author, MerC, writes:

> At the very end you are given a score (mine was 101,603 - whatever
>   that means) and invited to send it to the Hall of Heroes,
>   somewhere in the USA.

Sue, the publisher, adds:

> @~That's probably worth doing; I sent off my scores after playing
>   @~Might and Magic III and IV (same authors, New World) and got
>   @~very nice parchment certificates in return

So, assuming that New World Computing did the same thing for *Anvil of Dawn* scores like they (probably) did for *Might and Magic* scores, you would have got a **parchment certificate**.

(I welcome any first-hand experience to verify/debunk this. And I would love to see a photo of such a certificate, or whatever it may have been.)